# SwiftUI Button action statements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'd like to do a statement in button block, if textfield is empty, then get an alert and you can't acces the other ViewController, if you fill he textfield, then you can start play:

**LaunchView.swift :**

```
 Button(action: {
             if username.isEmpty {
                    showingAlert = true
                 } else {
                     //Here I would like to acces another view
                   }
              }) {
                 Text("PLAY")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .frame(width: 350)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                        .shadow(radius: 15)
                    
                }.alert(isPresented:$showingAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Error"),
                        message: Text("Enter your username"),
                        dismissButton: .cancel()
                    )
                }
```

And I have one more question, how could I use a variable from LaunchView, in FirstView?
Like, I would like to get the name from LaunchView's textfield, in alerts in FirstView:
"(username), your score is X"

**FirstView.swift**:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingScore) {
            Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message: Text("Your score is \(point)"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
                self.askQuestion()
            })
        }
```

Comment: I have read through this a few times, but I am not sure what you are asking. For the sake of terminology, SwiftUI does not have VCs, it has views. If you are asking how to access another view in the button, what view are you talking about? Also, your second question asks about a view that you haven't shown us. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Since you can't put a `View` there you need a variable `showingView = true` and use that variable to activate/show/trigger the `View` outside of the `Button`

Comment: You can share the `username` by passing it using an `@Binding` or sharing an `ObservableObject` or using some other form of storage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.